# Drag and drop in Grid layout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have the following grid layout set up in my XAML page.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        <BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
            <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_OnPanUpdated"/>
        </BoxView.GestureRecognizers>
    </BoxView>
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" />

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Purple" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Fuchsia" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="GreenYellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    </BoxView>

</Grid>
```

I want to add a drag and drop functionality on each box view. The idea is I should be able to drag each box view and drop it on another box view having the same column span. Can someone please advise me on how to do this ? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in drag and drop functionality in Xamarin.Forms just yet. You can still implement it yourself using `PanGestureRecognizer`.

You can add gesture recognizer to your view, for example `Label`, like this:

```
<Label>
   <Label.GestureRecognizers>
      <PanGestureRecognizer PanUpdated="PanGestureRecognizer_OnPanUpdated" />
   </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

Now in the `PanUpdated` event handler you can use `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` to move a view around.

```
private double _startTranslationX, _startTranslationY

private void PanGestureRecognizer_OnPanUpdated(object sender,
    PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    var box = (BoxView) sender;
    if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Started)
    {
        _startTranslationX = box.TranslationX;
        _startTranslationY = box.TranslationY;
    }
    else if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Running)
    {
        box.TranslationX = _startTranslationX + e.TotalX;
        box.TranslationY = _startTranslationY + e.TotalY;
    }
    else if (e.StatusType == GestureStatus.Completed)
    {
        box.TranslationX = _startTranslationX + e.TotalX;
        box.TranslationY = _startTranslationY + e.TotalY;
        //handle drop here (depending on your requirements)
    }
}
```

To actually implement a drop functionality you will have to manually test where the object is currently located and if dropping is allowed there.

Comment: Does it work with a box view ? How do I add the PanGesture ? 

If I want to swap these two `<BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Purple" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>`.. How can I do this ?

Comment: You can add the `PanGestureRecognizer` to the `BoxView` the same way I shown with the `Label` - just using `BoxView.GestureRecognizers` instead.

Comment: Yes. It moves the box view. But I want to drop it on another box view. It replaces the box view where I dropped it. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You will have to handle this manually in place I have marked //handle drop here. You will have to check if the current position is above the other box view (by comparing the coordinates) and if yes, you will reset the translation and then manually move the element there (by setting the `Grid.Column` and `Grid.Row` values properly)

Comment: I have applied the PanGesture to a specific BoxView (the red one). But the whole grid is moving. How can I prevent this ? I want the red box view to superpose on the aqua box view. Can you please advise ?

Comment: That should not be happening, could you update the question with code you have now?

Comment: I have updated the code, the previous one manipulated the `TranslationX` and `TranslationY` of the whole page, this should work better.

Comment: Updated code once more, the dragging didn't work properly, now should be better.

Comment: Also, if you want the `boxView` to be above everything else, you will probably have to remove it from the `Grid` and re-add it as the last child before you start dragging

Comment: I can't investigate further as I am leaving for a while, but maybe someone else might know how to go from here.

Comment: Do you have an idea bro? :(

Comment: @ Martin Zikmund : Could you update the code to make the box superpose on the other boxviews ? Right now, its going beneath.

Comment: I know, and I haven't found any properly working solution for that so far :(. If you take out the view out of the hierarchy, it will stop the pan gesture as well.

Comment: Yeah :( 

Do you have an idea about the drop zone though ?